# Low Search - option thats not in field being searched for

Tags: low-search, grid, options

My **Low search** form always searches for the first option in the field below (Grid column with value/label pairs) even if none of its options are selected.   Can anyone help me with this?

`http://mydomainname.com/index.php/properties?search:property_address_set:address_ward=Select+option`

```
<select name="search:property_address_set:address_ward">
    <option>Select option</option>
    {exp:low_options:property_address_set}
    {if option:group != ''}<optgroup label="{option:group}">{/if}
    {options}<option value="{option:value}">{option:label}</option>{/options}
    {if option:group != ''}</optgroup>{/if}
    {/exp:low_options:property_address_set}
</select>
```

**EE 3.5.2**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `value=""` to the first option. This is how HTML and forms work.

- This `<option>Hello World</option>` will submit `Hello world`
- This `<option value="hi">Hello World</option>` will submit `hi`
- This `<option value="">Hello World</option>` will submit an empty string